# Mutation plot splitting cohort

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioconductor, mutation, maf

I am approaching some R packages to create oncoplot representing different mutation types.
I am using maftools (oncoplot function) and genvisR (waterfall function) packages.
I would like to split results plot in two parts based on clinical information (like gender - male and female).

I want to reach a representation like this one but I can't find the correct parameter

[image: waterfall plot image]

Could someone help me? Is there a command inside the function or outside (like facet_wrap) to split to cohort based on clinical information? It should be very useful for me

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am unable to see data provided for the question. You might want to use facet_grid/wrap to make distinct plots for men-women.

Comment: Maftools will let you get close. Subset maf with `subsetMaf` to sepparate male and female samples into two different maf objects. then run the two objects through a `CoOncoplot` https://rdrr.io/bioc/maftools/man/coOncoplot.html.